# Laravel 7 Argon2 hashing not supported

Tags: php, laravel, argon

I'm trying to use argon2id in my laravel application

I changed the driver in hashing.php
from `'driver' => 'bcrypt'` to `'driver' => 'argon2id'`

then I tried run my seeders then it gave me an error

```
Argon2 hashing not supported.
```

Laravel version 7.29.2

Php Version 7.4.11

Here's the actual error

[image]

Comment: I think you need to have libsodium installed ? and php module sodium.. But I think it was integrated at 7.3 as a must so should be possible with 7.4

Comment: hi @Svetoslav upon checking libsodium is installed on my fedora 32 and the version is  1.0.18

Comment: Can you show your Seeder ?

Comment: @Svetoslav here's some of my seeder https://imgur.com/a/v340ZvY all of it have the same password format